# Converting SVG String to PNG with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, svgtopng

How can I convert a svg image string into png image with Codeigniter 3?

I tried to use imagick, but its not available.

```
public function convertSVGtoPNG($svgString, $outputFile) {

    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagick->readImageBlob($svgString);
    $imagick->setImageFormat('png');
    $imagick->writeImage($outputFile);
    $imagick->destroy();

    echo 'SVG saved as PNG successfully.';
}
```